# Proper way to label a group select elements

Tags: html

If I want to add a label to a text input I can do something like:

```
<label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" required>
```

But what is the best way of adding a label to a group of elements? Let's say I have a group of [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) elements representing a birthday:

[image]

The text "Birthday:" isn't tied to any specific select element but, instead, refers to all of them.

```
<label for="???">Birthday:</label>
  <select id="birthday-month" name="birthday-month" required>
    <option value="">Month</option>
    ...
  <select id="birthday-day" name="birthday-day" required> 
    <option value="">Day</option>
    ...
  <select id="birthday-year" name="birthday-year" required>
    <option value="">Year</option>
    ...
```

I'm obviously new to HTML but I am trying to learn how to do things the correct way so that people using screen readers, crawlers, etc. can understand my pages.